# Youtube Upload API returns videoId but video is not available on youtube

Tags: java, api, youtube-api

In the app, there is a block of code that looks similar to [official youtube sample](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#examples), which uploads video file using google's lib (`com.google.api`). Uploading goes well and in the end of processing the `id` of `com.google.api.services.youtube.model.Video` is printed in log file. So I'm sure that uploading itself works perfectly.

Uploading small video files (less then `15mb`) works. It is possible to see the resulting video on youtube, but it is not a case with a large `100+ mb` video files. Large files are uploaded and I can see `youtube id` in log files but video is not available on youtube itself.

here's the code excerpt

```
private static final String VIDEO_FILE_FORMAT = "video/*";
private static YouTube youtube;
private static final List<String> SCOPES = Lists.newArrayList(
        YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE,
        YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE_UPLOAD
);

private static int uploadToYoutube(BlablaConfiguration configuration, com.blabla.youtube.model.Video videoObject, String localFilename) {
    LOG.debug("UPLOAD_YOUTUBE");
    try {
        JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setServiceAccountId(configuration.getClientEmail())
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(configuration.getP12filename()))
                .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
                .setServiceAccountUser("my@account.com")
                .build();



        youtube = new YouTube.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(configuration.getAppName())
                .build();

        LOG.info("Uploading...");

        Video videoObjectDefiningMetadata = new Video();
        VideoStatus status = new VideoStatus();
        status.setPrivacyStatus("public");
        videoObjectDefiningMetadata.setStatus(status);

        VideoSnippet snippet = new VideoSnippet();

        StringBuffer title = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            String yearStr = Integer.toString(videoObject.getYear());
            title.append(yearStr);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //
        }

        String make = videoObject.getMake();
        if (make != null) {
            title.append(" " + make);
        }

        String model = videoObject.getModel();
        if (model != null) {
            title.append(" " + model);
        }

        String style = videoObject.getStyle();
        if (style != null) {
            title.append(" " + style);
        }

        snippet.setTitle(title.toString());
        snippet.setDescription("Video uploaded via Blabla.com");

        List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
        tags.add("http://www.blabla.com");
        snippet.setTags(tags);

        videoObjectDefiningMetadata.setSnippet(snippet);

        InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent(VIDEO_FILE_FORMAT,
                new FileInputStream(localFilename)
        );

        YouTube.Videos.Insert videoInsert = youtube.videos()
                .insert("snippet,statistics,status", videoObjectDefiningMetadata, mediaContent);

        MediaHttpUploader uploader = videoInsert.getMediaHttpUploader();

        uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(false);
        MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener progressListener = new MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener() {
            public void progressChanged(MediaHttpUploader uploader) throws IOException {
                switch (uploader.getUploadState()) {
                    case INITIATION_STARTED:
                        LOG.debug("Initiation Started");
                        break;
                    case INITIATION_COMPLETE:
                        LOG.debug("Initiation Completed");
                        break;
                    case MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS:
                        LOG.debug("Upload in progress");
                        LOG.debug("Upload percentage: " + uploader.getProgress());
                        break;
                    case MEDIA_COMPLETE:
                        LOG.debug("Upload Completed!");
                        break;
                    case NOT_STARTED:
                        LOG.warn("Upload Not Started!");
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
        uploader.setProgressListener(progressListener);
        Video returnedVideo = videoInsert.execute();
        String videoID = returnedVideo.getId();
        LOG.debug("\n================== Returned Video ==================\n");
        LOG.debug("  - Id: " + videoID);
        videoObject.setYoutubeId(videoID);
        return 0;
    } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
        LOG.error("GoogleJSONException");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 1;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 2;
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        LOG.error("Throwable: " + t.getMessage());
        t.printStackTrace();
        return 3;
    }
}
```

What could be an issue here? 
Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried

Comment: @Alok I've updated question with code included

Answer (score 0):

Youtube does a lot of post-processing once a video is uploaded and this time is directly proportional to the video time -- longer the video, longer the time it takes for them to process.

This may explain why while a videoId was assigned to your video, it does not show up just yet.

Give it some time and try again.

https://www.quora.com/Why-does-YouTube-take-so-long-to-process-videos-after-theyre-uploaded

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The video was uploaded yesterday and assuming that it should be post-processed, I would think that it should not take much time for 10 mins video.

Comment: If this issue persists, the only other explanation that I can think of is that the video probably got flagged for review -- Google uses a lot of video processing algorithms to see if a content violates copyrights, objectionable content etc. Best would be to check with Youtube Support, may be?